# Как вернуть массив объектов из VK API execute

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Есть знаменитый пример, возвращающий мемберов группы, на его основе сделал код, всё заработало. Однако когда я попытался расширить код, чтобы возвращать не одно поле массива, а несколько - получилась полная чушь.

Вот код:

```
var members = API.groups.getMembers({"fields":"sex,bdate","group_id": "30666517", "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "200", "offset": 0}).items;
var offset = 20;
while (offset < 200 && (offset + 0) < 2000)
{
    members = members + "," + API.groups.getMembers({"fields":"sex,bdate","group_id": "30666517", "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "20", "offset": (0 + offset)}).items;
    offset = offset + 20;
}
return members;
```

Возвращается вот такая ерунда:

```
{"response":Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,...}
```

Попытка вставить цикл на сервер выдала ошибку превышения количества разрешённого для выполнения кода. [VK API execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute)

JSON тоже не понимается. Как-то можно решить эту проблему, чтобы вернуть требуемые данные в удобоваримом формате? Особенно если список полей будет расширен до 10-20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

убрать запятую `+ "," +`

```
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"fields":"sex,bdate","group_id": "30666517", "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "20", "offset": (0 + offset)}).items;
```